# Elixir Credo - How to use one Enum.reject/2 instead of Enum.reject/2 |> Enum.reject/2

Tags: enums, elixir

What should I do if I receive a **credo-refactoring opportunities** warning like the one below?

`` One `Enum.reject/2` is more efficient than `Enum.reject/2 |> Enum.reject/2` ``

As an example, how can I recode the following function using **one** `Enum.reject/2` instead of `Enum.reject/2 |> Enum.reject/2` ?

```
  def my_reject_test() do
    (1..10)
    |> Enum.reject(&(rem(&1, 2) == 0))
    |> Enum.reject(&(rem(&1, 3) == 0))
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or/2` to combine the conditions:

```
iex> Enum.reject(1..10, &(rem(&1, 2) == 0 or rem(&1, 3) == 0))
[1, 5, 7]
```

The reason why credo points it out is because piping two `Enum.reject/2` will first generate an intermediate list and then walk it once again:

```
iex> 1..10
1..10
iex> |> Enum.reject(&(rem(&1, 2) == 0))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
iex> |> Enum.reject(&(rem(&1, 3) == 0))
[1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Yes, I don't get the warning anymore. You have written very clearly and easily to understand. Thank you so much sabiwara

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that would be:

```
(1..10)
|> Enum.reject(fn x -> rem(x, 2) == 0 || rem(x, 3) == 0 end)
|> IO.inspect()
```

For more complex scenarios, I sometimes end up using `Enum.reduce/3`, or consider adding a named private function to perform the logic (for readability).

It's a good reminder that traversing lists can be expensive (for long lists), so whenever possible, you should minimize the number of times you traverse them.  Using `Enum.reject/2` twice makes the algorithm O(2n) complexity, whereas using it only once keeps it at O(n) complexity.

Comment: This is awesome. You have written a very nice logical explanation by also referring to **complexity**. Also, as you recommend, the idea of converting `& Shorthand`  to `Anonymous Function` sometimes seems more understandable and readable to me as well. Thank you very much for your answer Everett, it is also solved my question.